# Не отрабатывает скрипт php на странице HTML

Tags: php, html

Есть HTML-форма, которая отвечает за выбор валюты (для отображения цен в таблице). C формой работает скрипт PHP, который бы позволил сохранить последнюю валюту, которую выбирал пользователь. Написал скрипт, но не могу проверить его работу, так как не знаю почему скрипт не может отработать.

Файл lr3.html:

```php
<form method="POST" action="lr4.php">
   <div id="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="currency" id="UAH" value="UAH" checked>UAH
      <input type="radio" name="currency" id="USD" value="USD">USD
      <input type="radio" name="currency" id="RUB" value="RUB">RUB
      <input type="submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

Файл lr4.php:

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['currency']) && $_POST['currency'] == "UAH") {
    setcookie('UAH', "true", 600, '/');
    setcookie('USD', "false", 600, '/');
    setcookie('RUB', "false", 600, '/');
    $UAH = 'checked="checked"';
    $USD = '';
    $RUB = '';
} else if(isset($_POST['currency']) && $_POST['currency'] == "USD") {
    setcookie('UAH', "false", 600, '/');
    setcookie('USD', "true", 600, '/');
    setcookie('RUB', "false", 600, '/');
    $UAH = '';
    $USD = 'checked="checked"';
    $RUB = '';
} else if(isset($_POST['currency']) && $_POST['currency'] == "RUB") {
    setcookie('UAH', "false", 600, '/');
    setcookie('USD', "false", 600, '/');
    setcookie('RUB', "true", 600, '/');
    $UAH = '';
    $USD = '';
    $RUB = 'checked="checked"';;
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['UAH']) && $_COOKIE['UAH'] == "true") {
    $UAH = 'checked="checked"';
    $USD = '';
    $RUB = '';
} else if (isset($_COOKIE['USD']) && $_COOKIE['USD'] == "true") {
    $UAH = '';
    $USD = 'checked="checked"';
    $RUB = '';
} else if (isset($_COOKIE['RUB']) && $_COOKIE['RUB'] == "true") {
    $UAH = '';
    $USD = '';
    $RUB = 'checked="checked"';
}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне немного интересно, зачем при имени поля `name="currency"` Вы проверяете наличие параметра с именем `radio`?

```php
<input type="radio" name="currency" id="UAH" value="UAH" checked <?= $UAH; ?> />UAH
...
if (isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] == "UAH") ...
```

> не могу проверить его работу, так как он не хочет срабатывать.

По этой причине и не срабатывает. Ознакомьтесь с [руководством по работе с формами](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php). А лучше - прочесть для начала все руководство с официального сайта, уверен - сразу станет проще отлаживаться.

P.S. Одна из самых полезных при отладке функций PHP - [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php). Она позволяет посмотреть, *что же именно* находится в переменной. Если, например, в код PHP включить

```php
echo '<pre>$_POST = ';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

то можно увидеть переданные скрипту методом POST параметры. Очень пользительно при отладке.

**Update**

По обновленному вопросу. Файл lr3.php

```php
<?php

$currencies = ['UAH', 'USD', 'RUB'];

// Если не установлено - установить начальное значение
$settedCurrency = $_COOKIE['currency'] ?? $currencies[0];

//если некорректное значение - установить начальное значение
$currentCurrency = in_array($settedCurrency, $currencies) ?
                   $settedCurrency : $currencies[0];
?>

<form method="POST" action="lr4.php">
   <div id="radio">
<?php
    foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
      echo "\t<input type=\"radio\" name=\"currency\" id=\"$currency\" value=\"$currency\"",
           $currency === $currentCurrency ? ' checked' : '', '/>', $currency, "\n";
    }
?>
   </div>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Файл lr4.php

```php
<pre>
<?php
echo '$_POST = ';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '$_COOKIES = ';
var_dump($_COOKIE);

$currencies = ['UAH', 'USD', 'RUB'];

// Если не установлено - установить начальное значение
$settedCurrency = $_POST['currency'] ?? $currencies[0];

//если некорректное значение - установить начальное значение
$currentCurrency = in_array($settedCurrency, $currencies) ?
                   $settedCurrency : $currencies[0];

if (($_COOKIE['currency'] ?? '') !== $currentCurrency) {
    setcookie('currency', $currentCurrency, time() + 600, '/');
}

echo "\n\nУстановлена валюта ", $currentCurrency;
?>
</pre>
<a href="lr3.php">Вернуться на lr3.php</a>
```

Comment: спасибо, за замечание. Поправил код - а все равно не работает. При обновлении страницы не сохраняется checked выбранного radiobuton.

Comment: И не сохранится. При обновлении страницы Вы получаете свой сгенерированній HTML, в котором Вы же сами и указали, что "checked" - это именно первый вариант. Браузер только _отображет_ то, что _Вы сгенерировали_ для него. Вы сказали - "UAH checked", он послушно показал. Так что либо ставьте "checked" там, где Вам надо, либо не жалуйтесь, что браузер не читает Ваши мысли. :)

Comment: Вставьте в php-код `echo '<pre>$_POST = ';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';` и добавьте его вывод в вопрос. Заодно не забудьте добавить кнопку submit в форму. Иначе как браузер узнает, что Вы хотите отправить данные формы на сервер?

Comment: И, кстати, что это за конструкция `<?= $UAH; ?>` внутри тэга `<input>`? (посмотреть html-код, который получил браузер, можо так: нажмите правую кнопку мыши на странице, выберите пункт "исходный код страницы")

Comment: имя переменной.

Comment: кнопку добавил, но по её нажатию просто открывается пустая вкладка. Если cheked убрать внутри HTML-формы, то по умолчанию не выбрана ни одна валюта.

Comment: Уж _это_ я понял. Я не понял, _задля чего Вы в первом тэге `<input>` ставите признак "checked" напрямую, затем в каждом тэге выводите значение неинициализированной переменной, а затем, в конце скрпта инициализируете эти переменные_? В момент вывода тэга `<input>` значение _неинициализированных_ переменных $UAH, $USD, $RUB **всегда** будет `null`, а приведение к строке значения `null` **всегда** даст пустую строку. И в лог PHP по каждому использованию неинициализированной переменной упадет по Notice'у.

Comment: если в первом <input> не поставить признак cheked, то в момент загрузки страницы не выбрана никакая валюта.

Comment: Это логично. Я так понимаю, Вы ни HTML, ни PHP толком не знаете и не имеете понятия что и как работает. Вам стоит взять в руки хорошую книжку, или найти в интернете курс "для начинающих", или просто пойти на курсы. Простой вопрос: в _незакрытом_ тэге `<form>` у вас указано `action="lr4.php"`. А какое имя имеет файл, в котором Ваша форма? Если "lr4.php", то посмотрите лог сервера, там наверняка появилось сообщение об ошибке. И в этом сообщении указано, что за ошибка, в какой строке. А var_dump() Вы в код так и не включили...

Comment: Форма в файле lr3.html, скрипт в файле lr4.php. Оба файла находятся в одной директории. Что нужно исправить чтобы скрипт заработал?

Comment: Ну, для начала - **правильно и корректно** дать исходные данные по вопросу. Чтобы можно было понять, **что** в **каком** файле находится и при необходимости воспроизвести проблему. После этого **внятно и не допуская неоднозначностей в понимании** сформулировать, что Вы ожидаете от работы скрипта, и что получили в результате его работы. Если есть какие-то нюансы в вопросе - не забудьте их указать. Все это указано в [как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Правильно сформулированный вопрос содержит в себе половину ответа.

Comment: Вопрос переформулировал чтобы была яснее проблема

Comment: Скорректировал ответ. Вернул привычные Вам 2 файла.

Comment: Оба файла с расширением php?

Comment: Ну да. Ведь в файле lr3.php выполняется код PHP. Он генерирует форму, выставляет "правильную" валюту. А как Вы хотели? :) Ведь в Вашем HTML-варианте выбранной **всегда** будет валюта "UAH".

Comment: У меня форма находится перед таблицей на страничке HTML (одностраничный сайт), как вставить эти скрипты, если их 2?

Comment: А как Вы собирались 2 приведенных в вопросе файла объединить со своим одностраничным сайтом? Примерно так же и объединить.